# Confluent Kafka S3 Connector doesn't upload to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm trying to follow the tutorial in this link http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-storage-cloud/kafka-connect-s3/docs/s3_connector.html#quickstart

I managed to create the topic and keyed in the data. However when I try to upload to S3, apparently everything is running fine without any error in the output in Terminal, but my bucket is still empty. Below are the last few lines from the output.

```
[2017-05-18 07:58:56,658] INFO Started S3 connector task with assigned 
partitions: [] (io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkTask:103)
[2017-05-18 07:58:56,661] INFO Sink task WorkerSinkTask{id=s3-sink-0} 
finished initialization and start 
(org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:232)
[2017-05-18 07:58:58,083] INFO Discovered coordinator Kafka:9092 (id: 
2147483647 rack: null) for group connect-s3-sink. 
(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:586)
[2017-05-18 07:58:58,181] INFO Revoking previously assigned partitions 
[] for group connect-s3-sink 
(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:397)
[2017-05-18 07:58:58,181] INFO (Re-)joining group connect-s3-sink 
(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:420)
[2017-05-18 07:58:58,361] INFO Successfully joined group connect-s3-
sink with generation 11 
(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:388)
[2017-05-18 07:58:58,369] INFO Setting newly assigned partitions 
[s3_topic-0] for group connect-s3-sink 
(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:256)
[2017-05-18 07:59:53,363] INFO Reflections took 89282 ms to scan 560 
urls, producing 12993 keys and 85595 values  
(org.reflections.Reflections:229)
```

Comment: Need more logs of the sink connector. What is the topic? Whether the data is consumed in respective topic.  Use below command to check the lag of the topic. sh ./bin/kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server localhost:9091 --new-consumer  --describe --group connect-{connectorName}. Other than this, check the policies/permissions on the S3 bucket.

Comment: The topic is called `s3_topic`. I followed exactly what's written in the tutorial.

In your command, what does `connectorName` stand for?

Comment: It would probably help if you could include your connector's configuration (java properties or json) that you use to start this connector instance. There's something probably a bit off if you don't see any exception in Connect logs. If I had to make a guess it would be that you may have to specify our AWS region as well using the property `s3.region` (the quickstart mentions this in a paragraph but not in the example config).

Comment: KelvinLowEeHahn What did you do to fix this?  I am facing the same issue..
I ran the command recommended by @Renukaradhya and it shows current offset and lag being "-" which I would take to indicate the connector is not reading the topic..  I am a bit at a loss for what to do..

Comment: @Procyclinsur I don't think I was able to fix it. I achieved my objective with another approach.

Comment: @KelvinLowEeHahn Thanks! I ended up doing the same thing, using fluentd (would have used logstash but it kept crashing in kubernetes)